# How to pass two callback to React.cloneElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am current passing two callback to a child component using

`React.cloneElement`

when inspecting my project I notice that `activeRow` is always present but `deactivateRow` is `undefined`.

Could you give me an idea of what can cause this problem?

```
export class Row extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    isActive: false,
  }
  activeRow = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true })
  }

  deactivateRow = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: false })
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { classes, children } = this.props
    const { isActive } = this.state
    return (
      <TableRow className={isActive ? classes.active: classes.noActive}>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
          activeRow: this.activeRow,
          deactivateRow: this.deactivateRow,
        })}
      </TableRow>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.cloneElement`, just clones a `single React element`, for cloning more that one children element, you need to map over all the children and clone them

```
export class Row extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    isActive: false,
  }
  activeRow = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true })
  }

  deactivateRow = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: false })
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { classes, children } = this.props
    const { isActive } = this.state
    return (
      <TableRow className={isActive ? classes.active: classes.noActive}>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
           return React.cloneElement(child, {
                  activeRow: this.activeRow,
                  deactivateRow: this.deactivateRow
              }
          }
       )}
      </TableRow>
    )
  }
}
```