# React Architecture Redesign

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, router, react-props

*Before we go any further: Redux or Flux is out of the question, not enough time to learn and properly test/implement/document*

Here is my top level component. The problem is that I need a way to store state for the children, but they aren't being rendered here hence the need for restructuring.

```
-- Both of these are in the render/return functions of my top level component

<SideNav {...tab_props} {...this.props} />
...
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { callback: this.callback.bind(this) })}
```

I am seeking advice on how to best redesign our front-end with the primary goal of minimizing requests, and ultimately cacheing needed data in state somewhere in the app. Thoughts?

Comment: SideNav looks like it's a common component for all. Why not render it higher up the stack?

Comment: if you do not want to use redux you can only use context or pass props through 3-4 components.

Comment: ^^ @Omar would it be acceptable to pass down the main values from state, to the first child component, and set state in that one as `this.props.--value--` and then pass down props from their to the 2nd child as `value={this.state.value}` such that the 2nd child is pulling from the original state?

Comment: theres no reason to do that just keep passing it down as this.props.value from the top level

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49156193/how-to-pass-two-callback-to-react-cloneelement/49156324#49156324

Comment: oh so cool! I just posted an answer that incorporates this approach. It is correct

Answer (score 0):

So, after much searching and research I stumbled on an awesome blog post that covers exactly what I need and it turns out I don't need to do the major restructuring that I initially thought was necessary.

Link > [Blog Post](https://codepen.io/Yuschick/post/react-passing-state-to-props-children-in-jsx)

So, what I am going to do is pretty simple. `React.cloneElement` is going to be used here. I will be mapping through all of the children, which are being rendered based on the URL (using react-router), and passing to them the state as well as some callback functions (not created yet for this use-case)

Would look something like this, I also tested it and it works!

```
render() {
let childWithState = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {state: this.state, callback: this.setParentState})
    })

...


return(
{childWithState}
)
}
```

So, now from any of these children elements, I only need to call on `this.props.state.--insert-something--` and I have access to is. If it doesn't exist, I can run my fetch request, and then in a callback function set the state in the parent, which would immediately re-render my component and give me access to the parent state!